# Rails testing without specifying exact wording

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm new to the concept of testing and there's one thing that's really putting me off. Currently I'm using rspec and capybara to make request tests. When I want to specify a user action, for example pushing a button or filling a form field, I have to provide exact wording for the field.

For example, when I had a `Reset` button and wrote `click_button 'reset'` in my test, it failed. Similarly, I had a field for `password_confirmation` property. However, I couldn't say to fill `password_confirmation` field, as it's id and name were extended (`user_password_confirmation` and `user[password_confirmation]` respectively). The easiest workaround was to use the label and write `fill_in 'confirm password'`.

Now, obviously when I'll want to rephrase the label or even change letter case, these tests will fail. Is there any option to make tests that will not be so strict on wording?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to make use of `I18n` (even if your app is one language only). Then, no matter what locale is set as default or how will you change the value in the future, you'll get "label agnostic" tests.

You'll just pass a key and get actual label.